# Upgrading jQuery from 1.3.2 and 1.4.2 to 1.5.1

Tags: jquery

In my project we have made many applications which consist of jQuery 1.3.2 and 1.4.2 code. Now we are planning to upgrade to jQuery 1.5.1. Can anyone tell whether 1.5.1 or its previous versions are backwards compatible with 1.3.2 and 1.4.2? It would also be great if anyone could point me to some discrete source (links). I have tried a lot while googling but found nothing much, just that 1.5.1 supports IE9.

Comment: Couldn't help but notice how "upgradation" sounds like such a mouthful. :D

Answer (score 3):

The API's for the main parts of Jquery haven't changed its mostly back end stuff and newer features that have been added.

see [release notes for 1.5.1](http://blog.jquery.it/2011/02/18/jquery-1-5-1-rc-1-released/)

Comment: thnx for ur help @ Decad. But i hv seen the release notes.
May be there is not much difference between 1.5 and 1.5.1. But what will happen if I upgarde my code from 1.3.2 to 1.5.1 and also when I upgrade my code from 1.4.2 to 1.5.1. Plz help me out

Comment: Can anyone atleast point me the difference between jquery 1.4.2 and 1.5.1. Is 1.5.1 backwards compatible with 1.4.2

Comment: http://blog.jquery.com/page/3/ is the release and change log to 1.5, as i understand it the backend to Ajax was rewritten.

Comment: With each iteration of an upgrade, the best thing to do is to actually just read the release notes. Whether or not your current code gets affected really depends on what feature/s you've used prior, and how you've implemented them in your code. That can be a really broad topic, and since you know your code best, something like this is best tackled by understanding the release notes themselves.